# (C#) SignalR 2.2.2 - Issue with project transferring from VS (sub 2017) to VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, visual-studio-2017, signalr

So it turns out that Microsoft offers a tutorial on how to make a web application for chat which can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr#setup

The setup is seemingly very simple but is tricky when it comes to which version of the code is compatible with the latest updates. One thing I will mention that worked was getting the prompt to pop up asking the user  to enter  their name. In order to do this I substituted given HTML code with this:

```
<title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>

<style type="text/css">

    .container {
        background-color: #99CCFF;
        border: thick solid #808080;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div class="container">

    <input type="text" id="message" />

    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />

    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />

    <ul id="discussion"></ul>

</div>

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>



<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {



        var connection = $.hubConnection();

        var chat = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');

        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.

        //var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.

        chat.on('broadcastMessage', function (name, message) {

            // Html encode display name and message.

            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();

            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

            // Add the message to the page.

            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName

                + '</strong>:  ' + encodedMsg + '</li>');

        });

        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.

        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));

        // Set initial focus to message input box.

        $('#message').focus();



        connection.start(function () {

            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {

                // Call the Send method on the hub.



                chat.invoke('Send', $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());

                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.

                $('#message').val('').focus();

            });



        });

    });

</script>
```

This seemed to do what was approriate as far as the popup window goes. But as far as seeing the actual output from the user on the display box, nothing is seen when the send button is pressed. Also, the new HTML code does seem to allow the VS 2017 programmer to clear the chatbox when the "Send" button is clicked. Can anyone find out what might be not up-to-date in this simple application?

This may be an update issue with SignalR or something...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your case and if my answer will solve your problem, but it seems that projects created in `VS 2017` contain the following instructions in their `csproj` files:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After stumbling upon a similar error, once I manually added the instructions above to my existing `csproj` file, my project finally managed to load in `VS 2017`.

To elaborate a little bit more, find the following text in the `csproj` file (which defines the importation the web application target):

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

and put the instructions just before it.